# window onload function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website where I am using window onload function which doesn't seems to be working for me. I went through the questions asked previously on the same topic and tried them too.

1) i tried:

```
$(window).load(function()
```

with

```
    $("#inline_content")
```

too. But no luck.

This is the script which is declared in the head:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"310px", height:"300px"});
});
</script>
```

and the body has:

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:20px; background:#eaeaea;'>
        <h4>Choose country</h4>
        <div class="content-box">
        <select>
            <option value="AU" data-icon="./img/dk.png">Danmark</option>
            <option value="CA" data-icon="./img/CA.png">Canada</option>
            <option value="PL" data-icon="./img/PL.png">Poland</option>
            <option value="TH" data-icon="./img/TH.png">Thailand</option>
            <option value="UK" data-icon="./img/UK.png">England (UK)</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').wSelect();
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button class="kontactButton3">vælg ></button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a plugin from [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Now [this is the link](http://goo.gl/fT6fMr) I am working on.

If the link "Inline HTML" is clicked, it does load the popup. But how can I get this as the first thing to happen when the page loads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inline').click();
});
```

Comment: Hah! that was pretty simple... i added
        $('.inline').click();
after my set of code in the head. and it's working like charm.
Thanks @Kareel.

Comment: @Sajal Please consider selecting an answer as the accepted answer if it helped you.